# How to spatially join a grid with a landuse layer in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, spatial-join

I'm new to QGIS and I'd like to know if exist in QGIS the equivalent command for "spatial join" of ArcGIS. I have tried with "join attributes by location" but seems to be impossible setting the match options. I have to find the correspondence between each element of a grid and a vector layer which represent the land use.

---

I'm dealing with two vector layers. What I have to do is associate to each polygon of the grid,the value of the class land use which cover the specific area. With "match option" I mean for example, the possibility to associate to each element of the grid only the class that fall in the centre of the area. (The land use is a v polygonnal vector layer)

Comment: What do you mean with "match options"?

Comment: are you dealing with 2 vector layers, or 1 vector and 1 raster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Grid layer needs a unique ID field, if you need to add one, calculate it to Row_Number. Create Centroids from the Grid layer. Join the Land Use to grid Centroids using "Join Attributes By Location". Finally, use Table Join from the Grid Layer Property to join the Centroid.LandUse to the original Grid layer, using the UniqueID from step one.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have followed your suggestions and the only problem is the warning message “Input layers have non-matching CRS" even if both layers have the same reference system. I have ridden a lot of forum but I'm not able to find a solution. I have also another query for you: what command I have to use if I deal with a vector layer and a raster? thanks everybody

Comment: I would convert the Raster to Vector, so both data layers are Vector.